# Angular js - optional dynamic url params

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url, pagination, routes

I've setted up a simple pagination url like this:

```
.when('/users/:offset/:filter/:keywords',{
          templateUrl:'views/users/index.html',
          controller:'Users',
          reloadOnSearch:false
        }) 
.otherwise({
          redirectTo:'/'
        });
```

now if i browse `site.co/users/5/1/heykeyword` it works

BUT if i browse `site.co/users/5/1` i get redirected to `/`

what's wrong?

Shouldn't routeParams be dynamic !?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that what you have written includes a must arguments,

you can achieve it by adding the 'keywords' as optional (by adding a question mark):

```
.when('/users/:offset/:filter/:keywords?',{
          templateUrl:'views/users/index.html',
          controller:'Users',
          reloadOnSearch:false
        }) 
.otherwise({
          redirectTo:'/'
        });
```

the offset & filter are required, but now the keywords parameters is optional.

For more info:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider

From angularjs documentation:

> path can contain optional named groups with a question mark:
>   e.g.:name?.

Comment: hey this i cool i didn't noticed about it, and it works great! thanks a lot going to accept in few seconds